# how to add an onMouseLeave & onMouseEnter to a .map function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to add a :hover effect to a .map function for creating three different buttons.

Here is my code:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state= {
   hovered: false
  }
  this.onMouseEnter = this.onMouseEnter.bind(this);
  this.onMouseLeave = this.onMouseLeave.bind(this);
}

onMouseEnter() {this.setState({hovered: false})}
onMouseLeave() {this.setState({hovered: true})}

render() {
const externalServiceButtons = {
  linkedin: {
    onClick: () => Meteor.loginWithLinkedin(),
    label: 'Linkedin',
    onMouseEnter: this.onMouseEnter,
    onMouseLeave: this.onMouseLeave
  },
  facebook: {
    onClick: () => Meteor.loginWithFacebook(),
    label: 'Facebook',
    onMouseEnter: this.onMouseEnter,
    onMouseLeave: this.onMouseLeave
  },
  google: {
    onClick: () => Meteor.loginWithGoogle(),
    label: 'Google',
    onMouseEnter: this.onMouseEnter,
    onMouseLeave: this.onMouseLeave
  }
}

    const authSocial = Object.keys(externalServiceButtons).map((key, index) => {
  const {
    color,
    label,
    onMouseEnter,
    onMouseLeave
  } = externalServiceButtons[key];

  return (
    <div
      key={index}>
      <FlatButton
        labelPosition='after'
        label={label}
        onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter}
        onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave}
      />
    </div>
   )
});
```

The problem I have is that when I hover in one button the others buttons disappear or turn to white or transparent.

Comment: if you remove the `bind(this)` does it work? you need `this` to be the button, not the constructor...right?

Comment: Hi @sweaver2112 if I remove the bind(this) then I get state is not defined :(